# Setting my paragraphs to begin at the top margin using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, itext

I'm trying to build pdf files to digitize our reporting system at my company. I've used iTextSharp and so far it looks great but my margins don't seem to be working properly. I've set the margins to a config file and the left and right margins are working great, but my paragraph seems to start about 30% down the page regardless of the top and bottom margin.
I've set the margins to 0. When the page is built, the first paragraph doesn't begin at the top margin. Any help with getting my paragraph to simply begin at the top margin would be really appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you reduce the *leading*? How do you set the margins to 0? What are you doing (show us your code) and what are you expecting (show us a screen shot of what is wrong according to you)? Your question is incomplete, and therefore unanswerable.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As long as you do not provide the code to reproduce the issue, we can merely say that you obviously do something wrong.